# Special Characters in SQLite Query (in iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5, sqlite

I'm using SQLite for an iPhone app and I'm using a query like this:

`NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Courses (name, credits, web, tName, tSurname, tMail, tOffice) VALUES (\'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\');", self.name, self.credits, self.web, self.tName, self.tSurname, self.tMail, self.tOffice];`

It is a simple INSERT, but I'm from Spain and I'm having some troubles with tildes. If i do something like:

`INSERT INTO Courses (name, credits, web, tName, tSurname, tMail, tOffice) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');", self.name, self.credits, self.web, self.tName, self.tSurname, self.tMail, self.tOffice];`

All works perfect.

The problem becomes when I do an insert with two or more words with "special characters" like ¿, ¡, `, ', ñ... And I don't know how to fix it :S If the query only contains a special character there is no problem.

For example:

This query is working (because there is only an "á"):

`INSERT INTO Courses (name, credits, web, tName, tSurname, tMail, tOffice) VALUES ('Matemáticas', '1', '', 'Name', 'Surname', 'a@a.com', '');", self.name, self.credits, self.web, self.tName, self.tSurname, self.tMail, self.tOffice];`

This query returns me the error "Error: near "''": syntax error" (because there are an "ó" and an "à"):

`INSERT INTO Courses (name, credits, web, tName, tSurname, tMail, tOffice) VALUES ('Gestió', '1', '', 'à', 'Surname', 'a@a.com', '');", self.name, self.credits, self.web, self.tName, self.tSurname, self.tMail, self.tOffice];`

I tried to put the words between " and between ' and I get the same.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solid solution to this problem, I am running through the same from last three days.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with SQLite on the iPhone but have you looked through the library to find some way of constructing a precompiled SQL Statement? This would solve a host of issues that you might encounter such as misinterpretations of SQL queries and accidental\intentional SQL Injection.

Comment: No, I haven't looked through the library. For more information I'm using the official libsqlite3.dylib that comes with Xcode. If someone knows any other library I will try it.